# Cloudformation Dependency Issue - AutoPublishAlias in AWS::Serverless::Function

Tags: aws-sam

I am using SAM template to deploy Lambda function and api gateway. I am using AWS::Serverless::Function to define my lambda function. I am using AWS::Serverless::Api to define my API. I am also using AWS::Lambda::Permission to grant permission to apigateway for the function.

The problem is resource creation of AWS::Lambda::Permission fails because my Alias is not available. My LambdaFunction resource creates the Alias but before even it is getting created the Lambda permission resource creation is triggered and it fails if it doesn't see the Alias mentioned.

i use "aws cloudformation deploy" to deploy the template

Adding DependsOn attribute to LambdaPermission resource doesn't work

```
> LambdaFunction:
>     Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
>     Properties:
>       Handler: MyHandler
>       Runtime: !Ref LambdaJavaVersion
>       CodeUri: ./build.jar
>       Description: !Sub "${LambdaName} function"
>       Role: !GetAtt LambdaIAMRole.Arn
>       FunctionName: !Ref LambdaName
>       AutoPublishAlias: prod
> APIResource:
>   DependsOn: LambdaFunction
>   Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
>   Properties:
>     DefinitionUri: ./swagger/swagger.yml
>     EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
>     StageName: prod
> 
> LambdaPermission:
>   DependsOn: 
>     - LambdaFunction
>     - APIResource
>   Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
>   Properties:
>     FunctionName: !Join
>       - ""
>       - [!GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn,":","prod"]
>     Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
>     Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
>     SourceArn: !Join
>         - ""
>         - [!Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}",':',!Ref
> APIResource,'/*/*/*']
```

I would like to create the LambdaPermission only after Alias is published.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After struggling with this myself, I found this in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-function.html#sam-specification-generated-resources-function-autopublishalias):

> **AutoPublishAlias Property Is Specified**
>
> When the AutoPublishAlias property of an `AWS::Serverless::Function` is
> specified, AWS SAM generates the following AWS CloudFormation
> resources:
>
> `AWS::Lambda::Alias` and `AWS::Lambda::Version`.
>
> **AWS::Lambda::Alias**
>
> LogicalId: `<function‑LogicalId>Alias<alias‑name>`
>
> <alias‑name> is the string that AutoPublishAlias is set to. For
> example, if you set AutoPublishAlias to live, the LogicalId is:
> MyFunctionAliaslive.
>
> *Referenceable property: `<function‑LogicalId>.Alias`*

The last line is the solution. So to make your permission depend on the alias, and therefore, get created only after the alias has been created, you can reference the alias this way:

**YAML**

```
LambdaPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction.Alias
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

**JSON**

```
"LambdaPermission": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties": {
    "FunctionName": {
      "Ref": "LambdaFunction.Alias"
    },
    "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  }
}
```

The `DependsOn` property is not necessary as the permission now implicitly depends on the alias to be created.

Comment: We should call out 2 items in more detail. 1) It does not matter what your AutoPublishAlias is set to, if it is set and you want it, always reference `.Alias`. 2) We exchange !GetAtt for !Ref: `!Ref LambdaFunction.Alias`.